# When to use super when overriding ios methods

Tags: ios, swift

My coworkers will sometimes call super when overriding an ios method and sometimes not. This seems to be mostly based on their experience. Is there a rule of thumb to use when deciding whether or not to call super?

Ex:

```
// Has super
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

// No super
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
}
```

Comment: @matt your comment helps nobody, please provide a reference to the docs or another SO post. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH17-ID196

Comment: @alexisSchreier I disagree. I've answered the question very directly, concisely, and correctly. To know whether to call super when implementing `awakeFromNib`, you have to read the docs on `awakeFromNib`. And so on. There is no shorter path. My comment helps _everybody_.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There isn't really a rule of thumb for whether or not you should call the super implementation of a given method. This is something that should be determined on a case by case basis, depending on recommendations from the documentation for the superclass' implementation of that method, and your requirements.

Just to explain why the two examples you included might be the way they are, we can look at the documentation for [-[UIView drawRect:]](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/drawRect:), which states:

> If you subclass UIView directly, your implementation of this method
>   does not need to call super. However, if you are subclassing a
>   different view class, you should call super at some point in your
>   implementation.

and the documentation for [-[NSObject awakeFromNib]](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSObject_UIKitAdditions/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/awakeFromNib), which states:

> You must call the super implementation of awakeFromNib to give parent
>   classes the opportunity to perform any additional initialization they
>   require. Although the default implementation of this method does
>   nothing, many UIKit classes provide non-empty implementations.

Most of the time, it's probably a safe bet that you should call the super implementation of a method (see comments below). However, be warned, some methods require you to call their super implementation, some don't, and some even require you to call the super implementation at a specific point in your override. So remember, when in doubt, always consult the documentation.

Comment: I would answer this differently. For beginning developers, I would say "always call the super implementation." If the compiler complains that the method isn't defined, remove the call. Sometimes you don't need to call super because the base class' super implementation does nothing, but it's safer to call it when you don't need to than to not call it when you DO need to.

Comment: @DuncanC That's a good point. Calling super when in doubt is probably a safer default position to take in the general case. Although, (and I'm failing to think of an example) it could be the case that the super implementation of a method has side effects that alter state that the code in your subclass' implementation had also altered. In which case, the placement of the super call within your override would matter, and could lead to further confusion.

Comment: I believe the norm is to call the super version first, then add your custom code. That way any changes you make to the method are applied after the super implementation does its thing.

Comment: @DuncanC Normally yes, although there are exceptions. For example [UIView updateConstraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/updateConstraints) documentation explicitly states "Call [super updateConstraints] as the final step in your implementation."

Comment: That's why I said "norm" rather than hard rule.

Comment: @i_am_jorf pointed out that for some classes/methods, you are explicitly NOT supposed to call the super implementation. Thus the answer really needs to be "you should probably call the super implementation of a method you override, but **always** read the documentation."

Comment: @DuncanC Sorry, wasn't trying to sound argumentative there, but that was  what I meant for my point to be in my answer. Since there are exceptions to be found in either direction, I find it important to always consult the docs. (edited answer to clarify) Thanks for the input.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118765/discussion-between-duncan-c-and-mick-maccallum).

Answer (score 0):

Sending a message to super is a way to call through to a method implementation defined by a superclass further up the inheritance chain. The most common use of super is when overriding a method. Calling super will allow the parent class to do some preparation. If you're overriding a method, you must call super else you might have some invalid state as super class implementation has missed initialising some states.

Comment: " If you're overriding a method, you must call super".That's not the case -  it depends on the particular method if it must or not.

Comment: Yes, for example [`UIViewController loadView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/loadView) explicitly says: "Your custom implementation of this method should not call super."  My advice is always check the documentation and when in doubt call super by default if the documentation doesn't say.  One nice thing about Android vs. iOS is you have the source code and can go see what super actually does.  :-/

Comment: @i_am_jorf  I don't see this stated anywhere in that document link.

Comment: Documentation has changed.  It's now stated [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621454-loadview).